# Get current user details in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is pretty direct forward but I have a problem with multiple users.When the first user signs in,his name and email are fetched with no issues but when he signs out and another user signs in (same phone), current user details return null.

```
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String uid = Objects.requireNonNull(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid();
        userDetails = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);
        myref.keepSynced(true);
        userDetails.keepSynced(true);

        name = view.findViewById(R.id.my_name);
        mail = view.findViewById(R.id.my_mail);
        userDetails.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String Name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String Email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();

                name.setText(Name);
                mail.setText(Email);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: The code you have above, is the activity containing it gets created again or not ?

Comment: your code looks fine, you are fetching user data on app start. so after signin it will get latest data.

Comment: Please add the database structure and the code where you are signin out.

Comment: Can u post the code, where u are implementing sign out method.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code is fine, only problem is my firebase structure. The first user "email" and "name" are in lowercase, the rest start with a capital letter   [users node, firebase Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVEuD.png)